# Day Night change with `PrefFragment`

Tags: java

there was a problem of change of a theme DayNight in my application.
I'm using `PreferenceFragment`

I get to change the theme, but sometimes the colors can be seen not correctly(
This is my Fragment:

```
public class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
    implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
public static final String NIGHT_MODE = "nightMode" ;
public static final String MAP_SWICH = "switch_preference_1" ;
public static final String Disable = "disabled";
public static final String Enable = "enabled";
private SharedPreferences preferences;
String versionName;
ListPreference nightSwich;


@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    nightSwich = (ListPreference)findPreference(NIGHT_MODE);

}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (key.equals(NIGHT_MODE)) {
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        nightSwich = (ListPreference)findPreference(NIGHT_MODE);
        String nightMode = preferences.getString(NIGHT_MODE, Disable);
        switch (nightMode) {
            case Disable:
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                break;
            case Enable:
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                break;
        }

       startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Drawer_main.class));
    }
```

But this is my Main Activity:

```
private static final String NIGHT_MODE = "nightMode" ;
public static final String Disable = "disabled";
public static final String Enable = "enabled";
private SharedPreferences mSettings;
private int mCounter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setCollapsible(true);
    initDrawer(toolbar);
    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());


    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String nightMode = preferences.getString(NIGHT_MODE, "");
    int themeMode = AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode();

    //mSettings = getSharedPreferences(NIGHT_MODE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    firstStartCheck();

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (nightMode)
        {
            case Disable:
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                break;
            case Enable:
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                break;
        }
        Class fragmentClass;

        fragmentClass = Fragment_taxi_0.class;
        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass
                    .newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container22, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is java, not javascript... the tag has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is clear
Why that did not change the colors that are registered through the attributes drawable xml

If to address at once through colors xml that all works well